# Unable to do post request on node.js server using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an index.js file which has code to handle get and post requests.

GET request is working pretty fine, the problem is with POST.

here is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("post request to index");
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Using Rest client, if I ping my server with a method, i am getting 400 error.

Please help.

Nikhil

Comment: I am getting 400 bad request when I try to hit the server with a POST method

Comment: Hi there! Could you edit your question to include your app code (eg, show us what other middleware you have attached, such as bodyParser) Also can you show us what kind of POST request you are making? Are you doing it with curl? postman? something else?

Comment: you have load this file in server.js ex require('./index.js')

Comment: Hi. I have resolved the issue. I have sent invalid json args as part of payload, hence the request was not even reaching the server. That's a stupid mistake. Thanks.